# Replacing gulp task with npm script

Tags: node.js, webpack, gulp, npm-scripts

I have a gulp task in my gulpfile.js as follows:

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
    let webPath = './webpack.config.dev.js';

    if (process.env.var) {
        webpackConfigPath = './webpack.config.' + process.env.var + '.js';
    }

    const webCon = require(webPath);

    return gulp.src('/js/index.js')
        .pipe(webpackStream(webCon, require("webpack")))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(BUILD_PATH));
});
```

To replace this and get rid of my gulp dependency, I am using the fs-extra package, and wrote a function as follows:

```
function buildApp() {
    let webPath = '/webpack.config.dev.js';
    if (process.env.var) {
        webpath = '/webpack.config.' + process.env.var + '.js';
    }
    const webCon= require(webpackConfigPath);

    let readStr = fs.createReadStream('/ui/js/index.js');
    let writeStr = fs.createWriteStream('/src/main/resources/public/app.js');

    readStr.pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig, require("webpack")))
        .pipe(writeStr);
}
```

However, this throws up an error, which says

```
TypeError: file.isNull is not a function
    at Stream.<anonymous> (path\node_modules\webpack-stream\index.js:95:14)
    at Stream.stream.write (path\node_modules\through\index.js:26:11)
    at ReadStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:727:22)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at internal/fs/streams.js:191:12
    at FSReqCallback.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:470:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! esg-scoring-model@0.0.1 build: `node build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the esg-scoring-model@0.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     path\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-27T20_31_56_858Z-debug.log
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is it failing, like which call?

Comment: @Mikkel it is failing at the readStr.pipe(...) call

Comment: I suspected that might be the case. I think the `require("webpack")` should be ok, and assuming `webpackStream` is a webpack function it must be the `webpackConfig` that is wrong. The code snippet doesn't show how that gets defined

Comment: @Mikkel you were right, i took another look at my webpack config file and figured out the issue. Thank you!